# Is there documentation for Team Build 2010 Activites?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

As most of you know TFS Team Build 2010 is Windows Workflow based.  It comes with a handful of custom Activities out of the box.  Is there any documentation available for these activities?

For example Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.GetBuildAgent is one of the activities that has basically only one property called Result which I'm assuming takes a variable name that receives the agent name.  But how does it determine which agent to select? which variables/arguments does it use to receive input/output?  I'm sure if I ask around I can figure out how this specific Activity works, but what about the other 50 activities?  I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation on these Microsoft provided activities to date.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no documentation on these activities. I have seen some previews on a book on Team Build that will arrive soon (keep an eye on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/)) and the VS ALM rangers who will bring their guidance on codeplex during the beginning of CY11.

Answer (score 0):

See [Team Foundation Build Activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx) on MSDN for documentation on all the included build activities.

The `GetBuildAgent` activity can only be used within an `AgentScope` activity. It returns the `IBuildAgent` object of the build agent that it is running on.

William's book on **[Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](http://tinyurl.com/InsideTFSBuildBook)** will also cover these build activities in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the built-in activities, I immediately found a need to implement custom activities.  Some Custom Activity examples are:

- Checking in/out a file in the build process
- Updating Version properties (to support ClickOnce deployment)
- Updating deployment folder html file to support Version updates

I found [an article by Jakob Ehn](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/08/13/tfs-team-build-2010-working-with-custom-code-activities.aspx) very helpful in navigating through this process.

[Ewald Hofman has a very thorough guide](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) to help you get more out of customizing Team Build.  It acts as a great reference.